# Instantiating unknown generic type with unknown generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection, activator

I am trying to build a plugin engine. The only requirement is that a plugin must implement two types: `ISettings` and `IPlugin` from the `contract.cs` below. A basic implementation of a plugin can be found in `plugin.cs`.

The main application will scan for assemblies implementing these types, creates instances of them and calls the standard `Start()` method.

It works fine, but I am missing any compile time check because I cannot correctly cast the instances to the desired types in `main.cs` (I know nothing about `plugin.cs` in the main app), that's why I am using `dynamic`.

The main reason for using a generic type is to give access to implementor of `plugin.cs` to his `TSettings` type. I could use `IPlugin<ISettings>` instead but this will oblige the implementor to write `Start(ISettings settings)` which makes `TSettings` unusable without a cast.

Another approach was to follow the official `IOptions<TSettings>` pattern, but the settings object cannot be injected into constructor because settings are built or modified after object creation.

I there any better way to design the contract or to obtain a strong typed reference in `main.cs` instead of dynamic?

Please note that this is a stripped down example to illustrate the principle, in reality the plugin interface is more complex, `TSettings` is used in more places and I am using dependency injection instead of the classic `Activator`.

contract.cs

```
interface ISettings {}

interface IPlugin<TSettings> where TSettings: ISettings
{
  void Start(TSettings settings);
}
```

plugin.cs

```
class SomeSettings: ISettings {}
class SomePlugin<SomeSettings> : IPlugin<SomeSettings>
{
  void Start(SomeSettings settings) { }
}
```

main.cs

```
void Load()
{
  Type settingsType = ... // extract settings type from plugin.dll
  Type pluginType = ... // extract plugin type from plugin.dll

  dynamic settings = Activator.CreateInstance(settingsType);
  //all I know is that settings can be cast to ISettings
  dynamic plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType)
  //all I know is that plugin can be cast to IPlugin<UnknownSettings>

  plugin.Start(settings)
  //it works but plugin being dynamic, I can write anything here.
}
```

**Clarifications**

- `plugin.cs` is developped by a third party, I don't have access to it. All I got is the resulting `plugin.dll`.
- I cannot cast to `IPlugin`, since the implemented interface is `IPlugin<T>`. I need `T` to provide settings later in `Start()`
- Dependency injection works as long as I provide the settings by injection in constructor only. But the settings are mutable during the object lifetime and I provide them to the implementor in different methods defined in `IPlugin<T>`. Since I am the provider of settings of type `T`, I cannot delegate this responsibility to the implementor to find them himself.

Comment: _“I know nothing about plugin.cs in the main app”_ Why? Then what's the point of defining these 2 interfaces?

Comment: I prefer to use dependency injection for situations like this. That way you only need the `IPlugin` interface and the implementor only needs to be concerned with how it gets it's settings.

Comment: When you know your instance will be an `IPlugin`, you should be able to cast to that interface, shouldn't you? `IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin) Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType)`